# python pandas binning numerical range

Tags: python, pandas, numeric, binning

I have a reqt., where I want to bin a numeric value

```
If the student marks is 
b/w 0-50 (incl 50) then assign the level column value = "L"
b/w 50-75(incl. 75) then assign the level column value ="M"
>75 then assign the level column value ="H"
```

Here is what  I have got

```
raw_data = {'student':['A','B','C'],'marks_maths':[75,90,99]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['student','marks_maths'])
bins = [0,50,75,>75]
groups = ['L','M','H']
df['maths_level'] = pd.cut(df['marks_maths'], bins, labels=groups)
```

I get a syntax error

```
File "<ipython-input-25-f0b9dd609c63>", line 3
    bins = [0,50,75,>75]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I reference a cutoff that says >certain value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 bins = [0,50,75,101] or bins = [0,50,75,np.inf]
```

Comment: the max could be 101 or 1000..i do not know ..so i want to just put a condition that it is > certain value

Comment: I originally upvoted this answer, but it doesn't make sense. You can't have an assignment in an `or` statement. What did you mean here?

Comment: @Ami  What are you talking about? The 'or' is English 'or', not code 'or'

Comment: Oh, so it shouldn't be formatted together as a single code block, right? The `or` appears here as a keyword.

Comment: It quite obvious to anyone using the site, what above means.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# 20 random numbers between 0 and 100
scores = np.random.randint(0,100,20)
df = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['scores'])

bins = [0,50,75, np.inf]

df['binned_scores'] = pd.cut(df.scores, bins=[0,50,75, np.inf], include_lowest=False, right=True)
df['bin_labels'] = pd.cut(df.scores, bins=[0,50,75, np.inf], include_lowest=False, right=True, labels=['L','M','H'])
```

The `include_lowest` and `right` arguments let you control whether your bins' edges are inclusive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the upper bound as the best possible mark:

```
bins = [0, 50, 75, 100]
```

The result is as you expect:

```
  student  marks_maths maths_level
0       A           75           M
1       B           90           H
2       C           99           H
```

Comment: You can also use np.inf if you don't want any bound.

Comment: the upper range can be anything..it can be 100 or 1000.i do not know the max /upper value